# Can Python call Delphi functions in a DLL?

Tags: python, delphi, dll, ctypes

I am trying to call functions from a DLL which seems to be created in Delphi. An example of a some functions supported by the DLL are:

```
function oziDeleteWpByName(var name:pansichar):integer;stdcall
```

The Python code I have written to access the above functions is not working.

```
from ctypes import *
libc = cdll.OziAPI
name ='test'

pi = pointer(name)

delname = libc.oziDeleteWpByName

delname(name)
```

It seems I am passing the wrong data type to the function. Any ideas on how to do it right?

Thanks it worked. Now please help with this function:

function oziGetOziVersion(var Version:pansichar;var DataLength:integer):integer;stdcall;
The version of OziExplorer is returned in the Version variable.

Now how do I pass 'var version' when it the one which will also be returned.

Comment: `var name:pansichar` implies that the `name` parameter can be modified and returned to the caller. Does the function really do that? Are you planning to read the contents of `name` after the function returns?

Comment: Also, which version of Python are you using? Can make a difference to string encodings.

Comment: yeah, that `var` declaration is fishy. If you, user 1138... wrote that DLL, why did you do that?

Answer (score 13):

```
from ctypes import *

# Not strictly needed but it's good to be explicit.
windll.OziAPI.oziDeleteWpByName.argtypes = [POINTER(c_char_p)]
windll.OziAPI.oziDeleteWpByName.restype = c_int

p = c_char_p('test')
retval = windll.OziAPI.oziDeleteWpByName(byref(p))
```

Comment: Updated with `argtypes` and `restype`.

Comment: My python isn't able to find windll.OziAPI - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910191/windll-oziapi-windowserror-module-not-found

Answer (score 1):

In Delphi, a `var` parameter is passed by reference.  So what you have there is a pointer to a `PAnsiChar` (aka C-style string pointer).  If you're passing it a string pointer, instead of a pointer to a string pointer, it won't work.

Comment: I also don't see in that Python code anything which suggests you're specifying the `stdcall` calling convention. Doesn't `cdll` in Python default to `cdecl`? If so, this will also cause you problems!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that anything you invoke via a dll and which the python runtime library loads and invokes, will always use the windows standard calling conventions.

Comment: @Warren No, LaKraven is right. `cdll` vs `windll` is the way to specify calling conventions. Also, there is no Windows standard for calling convention, at least on x86. Some libraries use `stdcall` and some use `cdecl`. Think of msvcrt for example. It's all `cdecl`.

Comment: Oh right. My bad.  I am so Delphi centric that I think of stdcall as a Windows standard but it isn't.  It's kind of the usual thing for "visual basic and delphi guys".

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's the first time you and I have agreed today :)